# Nested JSON Objects: Remove reference to source level JSON in CSV Export

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I am building an application that converts JSON in the following form to CSV:

```
[
{
    "_type":  "End",
    "_source": {
        "timestamp_milli": 1499696661704,
        "timestamp": "2017-07-10T14:24:21.704Z",
        "country": "United States",
        "country-code": "US"
    }
},
{
    "_type": "Info",
    "_source": {
        "timestamp_milli": 1499696614807,
        "timestamp": "2017-07-10T14:23:34.807Z",
        "country": "United States",
        "country-code": "US"
    }
},
{
    "_type": "Menu",
    "_source": {
        "timestamp_milli": 1499696578167,
        "timestamp": "2017-07-10T14:22:58.167Z",
        "country": "United States",
        "country-code": "US"
    }
}
]
```

Right now I am using the jsonexport npm package, which generates a CSV file for the above JSON document in the following form:

```
_type,_source.timestamp_milli,_source.timestamp,_source.country,_source.country-code
End,1499696661704,2017-07-10T14:24:21.704Z,United States,US
Info,1499696614807,2017-07-10T14:23:34.807Z,United States,US
Menu,1499696578167,2017-07-10T14:22:58.167Z,United States,US
```

I am stuck trying to remove the "_source." text from the headers of the generated .csv file. The JSON document will always have the same structure, but the elements in "_source" will change based on user input. I am trying to accomplish this without hard coding any of the keys from the JSON.

Could someone help me figure out the best way to go about this using node.js? A few different ideas I have are removing the "_source" level from the JSON document, or trimming the "_source." text from the csv file before I return it to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[
    {
        "_type" : "End",
        "_source" : {
            "timestamp_milli" : 1499696661704,
            "timestamp" : "2017-07-10T14:24:21.704Z",
            "country" : "United States",
            "country-code" : "US"
        }
    },
    {
        "_type" : "Info",
        "_source" : {
            "timestamp_milli" : 1499696614807,
            "timestamp" : "2017-07-10T14:23:34.807Z",
            "country" : "United States",
            "country-code" : "US"
        }
    },
    {
        "_type" : "Menu",
        "_source" : {
            "timestamp_milli" : 1499696578167,
            "timestamp" : "2017-07-10T14:22:58.167Z",
            "country" : "United States",
            "country-code" : "US"
        }
    }
].map((item) => {
    // assign nested properties from _source
    Object.assign(item, item._source);
    // remove _source from item
    delete item._source;
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, got it using this:

https://gist.github.com/Joeymarinello1/7af1d759528da8af63a87edd151a6c09

Thank you!